# CLIPS: Not conditional element around class instance match

Tags: clips

I read that

> CLIPS also gives you the capability of specifying an explicit not conditional element on the LHS. 
>   The absence of a fact is specified as a pattern on the LHS using the “not” conditional element.

Yet, the below code gives me a `[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for the not conditional element.`

```
(not
    (object (is-a clips_ASDF)
        (name ?some_name)
        (property ?my_property_var))
    (test (eq ?my_property_var nil)))
```

This however does not cause an error:

```
    (object (is-a clips_ASDF)
        (name ?some_name)
        (property ?my_property_var))
    (not
        (test (eq ?my_property_var nil)))
```

Why is that? How can I do the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **not** conditional element can only can a single conditional element. If you want to place more than one, surround them with an **and** conditional element:

```
   (not (and (object (is-a clips_ASDF)
                     (name ?some_name)
                     (property ?my_property_var))
             (test (eq ?my_property_var nil))))
```

Alternately, there's no need for a separate **test** conditional element:

```
   (not (object (is-a clips_ASDF)
                (name ?some_name)
                (property nil)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fit your needs:

```
(defrule my-rule      
    (object (is-a clips_ASDF) (name ?some_name) (property ?my_property_var)&:(neq ? my_property_var nil))
    =>
    (printout t "done" crlf))
```